# Approximating Unit covering of d-dimensional points

Tags: discrete-geometry, covering

Given a $d$-dimensional disk of radius $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, how many disks of radius $1$ suffice to cover it. Of course, it's fine if the smaller disks overlap. What matters is to specify a finite set of disks of radius $1$ (preferably with minimum size) such that any point in the larger disk is in one of the smaller ones.

For the simplest case $d = 1$, any disk of radius $r$ turns out to be a line segment of length $2r$ and therefore, the answer of the question is obviously $2$ (since $2$ segments of length $l$ can cover a segment of double length).

Comment: The title does not adequately reflect the question. In the first place, what is a $d$-*dimensional point* ? Then, in the question, you want to cover a $d$-dimensional "disk" (or rather a ball), not a point.

Comment: Let $d\ge 2$ be an integer. Your question is a special case of the following, well-known question about covering a ball: Given an integer $k\ge d$, what is the minimum radius of $k$ congruent balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that can cover the unit ball? The answer is known only for a finite number of values of $k$ for every $d$. A related, more extensively studied question is: What is the maximum radius of $k$ congruent balls that can be packed inside a unit ball?

Comment: Correction: In the covering question, I meant $k\ge d+1$, since for $k=d$ the answer is obvious: $r=1$.